# problem with query

Tags: mysql, database

what i am trying:

```
SELECT 
`update_photo`, 
(SELECT substring_index (`username`, ' ', 1)), 
`id_user`
FROM users 

JOIN worker_has_profession
ON worker_has_profession.worker_single_user_users_id_user  = users.id_user

ORDER BY `registration` 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

The output will be:

```
path photo | John | 31
```

but i need something like this (profession is in another table)

```
path photo | John | 31 | designer
```

**Tables**

```
   <table worker_has_profession>
    worker_single_user_users_id_user //same id of id_user
    profession_id_profession 

      worker_single_user_users_id_user            profession_id_profession 
                    31                                      10


   <table profession>
    id_profession 
    profession

     id_profession               profession 
           10                      designer
```

Any idea?

Comment: So why don't you select necessary field then?

Comment: how? the field that i need is in another table

Comment: you have already added one join, so add another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added the join below and profession to select list.

```
SELECT 
update_photo, 
(SELECT substring_index (`username`, ' ', 1)), 
U.id_user,
P.profession
FROM users U

JOIN worker_has_profession WP
ON WP.worker_single_user_users_id_user  = U.id_user

JOIN profession P
ON P.id_profession =  WP.profession_id_profession
ORDER BY registration
DESC LIMIT 10
```